# Set Windows Forms Background Color To Hex Value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am simply trying to set the background of a Windows Forms window to a hex color value, eg, "#626262."
I cannot seem to find any simple way to do it.
Is there a simple way to set the background color of a windows form?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Hex values are represented in C# like `0x626262`.

So you can simply enter that into the property editor.

If you want to do it at runtime, you can use `ColorTranslator`:

```
myForm.BackColor =  ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#626262");
```

Answer (score 3):

> **ColorTranslator.FromHtml** method translates an HTML color representation to a GDI+ Color structure.

1. Create a string representation of HTML color.
2. Translate htmlColor to a GDI+ Color structure.
3. Assign that color to your windows form background.

### Code

```
string hexColor = "#626262";

Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexColor);

form1.BackColor = myColor;
```